# How to get a document notarized in Australia?

Tags: australia

My friend is living in Australia. He wants to notarize a self-declared affidavit and send it to the USA. Where are the places he can have that affidavit notarized?

Comment: No idea whether this site is "safe", but http://www.notarylocator.com.au/notaries-explained.php

Comment: This problem faces locals just as equally as expats and is unfortunately not expats-specific.  I'm closing the question as such.  (However, as someone living in Aus, a Justice of the Peace or lawyer. Or go to the nearest police station like I did, they had a list of people you could use)